# Prove: Group of order $2^{13}\cdot 13$ has a normal subgroup

Tags: sylow-theory

Prove that a group of order $2^{13}\cdot 13$ has a proper normal subgroup.

Let $n_2$ be the number of sylow $2$ subgroups and $n_{13}$ the number of $13$ sylow subgroups. By the sylow theorems have $n_2 \mid 13$ and $n_2 \equiv 1 \mod 2$ and $n_{13}\mid 2^{13}$ with $n_{13} \equiv 1 \mod 13$.

Claim either $n_2=1$ or $n_{13}=1$, assume by contradiction that not the case, then we have $n_2 = 13$ and $n_{13} = 2^{12}$. Counting elements since $13$ sylow subgroups cyclic they have trivial intersection. Then we have $12(2^{12}) = 12 \cdot 2^{12}$ distinct elements of order $13$, on the other hand each $2$ sylow subgroup contains $2^{13}$ elements, we cannot say that they have trivial intersection right? Then how to proceed?

Thanks

Comment: There are much more options for $n_{13}$, not just the ones you mentioned. I don't think this method will work here. See my answer for a different method.

Comment: $2$ as an element in $Z_{13}^{\times}$ has order $12$ thats why $2^{12}\cong 1 \mod 13$ and nothing less than $12$ would satisfies $2^k \cong 1 \mod 13$

Comment: No, it is incorrect, Sylow theorem says $n_2| |G|$, hence $n_2|(3^{13}\cdot 13)$, and you can't say $n_2=1$ or $n_2=13$. There are much more choices for $n_2$. @IrbidMath

Comment: Since $2^{13} \cdot 13$ has exactly $2$ distinct prime factors, Burnside's Theorem guarantees that the group is not simple.

Comment: @TravisWillse I will look into that theorem, first time heard about it, thanks for the insight.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to show your group $G$ is not simple. Assume it is simple. Then $n_2\ne 1$, and so $n_2=13$. Define an action of $G$ on the collection of $2$-Sylow subgroups $Syl_2(G)$ by conjugation: $g.P=gPg^{-1}$. The action induces a group homomorphism:

$\varphi:G\to S_{Syl_2(G)}\cong S_{13}$

by $\varphi(g)(P)=g.P=gPg^{-1}$. Since $G$ is simple by assumption, $\varphi$ must be either trivial or injective. It can't be injective because $|G|=2^{13}$ does not divide $13!=|S_{13}|$. And it also can't be trivial. Indeed, let $P,Q$ be two distinct $2$-Sylow subgroups. By the Sylow theorems they are conjugate, i.e there is some $g\in G$ such that $gPg^{-1}=Q$. Then this $g$ satisfies:

$\varphi(g)(P)=gPg^{-1}=Q\ne P$.

And so $\varphi(g)\ne id$. So $\varphi$ is neither trivial nor injective, a contradiction.

Comment: No, it is incorrect, Sylow theorem says $n_2| |G|$, hence $n_2|(3^{13}\cdot 13)$. Why you claim $n_2=13$? There are much more choices for $n_2$.

Comment: @GGplay I edited the question the group order is $2^{13}\cdot 13$ am sorry.

Comment: @GGplay You are right, I missed this. OP wrote in his attempt that these are the two options, and I somehow didn't check it. But looks like it was a mistake in the question itself. I edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: @GGplay I'm confused. Did OP edit their question after this answer was posted? I think there is/should be some kind of rule against that.

Comment: @TravisWillse I think what you need for this argument to work is that $|G|\nmid |S_{n_2}|=n_2!$. I don't think that this follows from just $n_2\neq 1$. By the way, if I'm not mistaken, the same argument works for groups of order $2^{p}\cdot p$ as well.

Comment: @richrow Ah yes, you're right, of course.

Comment: @DavidLui The initial version of OP is $|G|=12^{13}\cdot 13=2^{13}\cdot 3^{13}\cdot 13$. That's why I post the comment saying this solution is incorrect. Later on the author changed the OP to $|G|=2^{13}\cdot 13$.